# I'm getting java.lang.RuntimeException in solr

Tags: solrj

**I'm getting above exception and failed to indexing the data to solr**

```
Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query:
select * from workbook Processing Document # 1
```

Comment: sorry, i'm not a wizard

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the url parameter. If the MySQL database is on the same machine, then use `url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb"` If its on www.mysite.com, then use `url="jdbc:mysql://www.mysite.com/mydb"`

Also, your log files may have more details regarding the error - please go through the logs and post the appropriate entries here.

**NEW EDIT ON REQUIREMENT**

Under  solr-dataconfig.xml

Check this

```
<dataSource name="jdbc" driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.1.25:1521/UNIDEV"  username="test"/>
```

Comment: <dataSource name="jdbc" driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.1.25:1521/UNIDEV"/>